# How do I manage file permissions using java for other users on a Windows VM

Tags: java, windows, jmeter

I am writing a Jmeter script and am unstuck on some file handling which I am controlling in a JSR223 sampler. The problem is that I need to create a local file, but if that filename already exists, I want to delete it before recreating it. My code works fine on my laptop (Windows 10), but I am now in the process of porting my Jmeter script to a Virtual Machine in my test environment and that seems to be part of the issue.  The VM is running Windows Server 2019, but that is academic.  I am RDC'd to that machine using my standard internal corporate credentials.

My question is: How can I either force a delete of the file, or separately modify its system access permissions so that the delete may proceed.

I am a novice Java coder, but otherwise an experienced integrator and have broad experience across many coding languages extending back over 30 years.

**Java versions:**

- My local machine: v8 Update 261
- Virtual machine: v8 Update 261

**Jmeter Versions:**

- My local machine: Jmeter 5.2.1
- Virtual machine: Jmeter 5.3

The root cause seems to be that on the VM, when my Jmeter task creates the file and then I check it in Windows explorer: my account has full permissions, whereas a local 'Users' account on the host only has read permissions (see attached screenshot). On the occasions when my code needs to delete the file, it seems that the Jmeter script only accesses the read-only version, and so cannot delete it or overwrite it.
[File properties per different users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdgtc.png)

Note that if I manually edit the access properties in Windows so that the local user has full access, then my code runs without any problems and the file is deleted.

When the delete method is reached, my console log reports the following message:

> JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script Build plink Script File (BSS
> MNP File ), message: javax.script.ScriptException:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\SLAB Automation\Jmeter
> Scripts\scripts\check_bss_mnp_BRP_files.plink (Access is denied)

Here is my code, which is Java inside a Groovy Scripting Engine.

```
//  if the file exists. If it does, delete it and recreate it.
f= new File(fPath);
if (f.exists()) { 
    log.info("File " + fName + " exists.. deleting it.");
    System.gc();            // Run Garbage collection (Found a solution that suggests to do this, but it makes no difference)
    f.setWritable(true);    // Try modifying the permissions; also fails.
    f.delete();             // *** Here is my problem ***
} 

// Open File 
f = new FileOutputStream(fPath, false);     // Second param: true to append; false to overwrite (what we want)
p = new PrintStream(f); 
// Write data to file 
p.println( "*** my content ***");
// Close File(s)
p.close();
f.close();
log.info("-- Created file: " + fPath);
```

And for anyone in need of the stack trace, here it is for completeness:

```
2020-09-09 18:32:21,317 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script Build plink Script File (BSS MNP File ), message: javax.script.ScriptException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\SLAB Automation\Jmeter Scripts\scripts\check_bss_mnp_BRP_files.plink (Access is denied)
javax.script.ScriptException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\SLAB Automation\Jmeter Scripts\scripts\check_bss_mnp_BRP_files.plink (Access is denied)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:222) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:72) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:630) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_261]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\SLAB Automation\Jmeter Scripts\scripts\check_bss_mnp_BRP_files.plink (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:72) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:263) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:286) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at Script115.run(Script115.groovy:40) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you do following and check if it works ?

1. Ensure directory/folder D:\SLAB Automation\Jmeter Scripts\scripts\ exits in the machine where JMeter script is executed.

> It is a good practice to avoid using spaces in directory/folder names. You may remove the spaces in the directories and update the test plan accordingly.

2. Please ensure the logged in user has permission to read/write files into the system. Looks like you don't have any issue here according to your input
3. Can you try to run the groovy script using Java IDE like IntelliJ idea and confirm that your script is working on your VM too.

I hope this is useful for you.

Comment: Hi Janesh, thanks for your suggestions. I shall take a look soon.

Comment: Also, on your point number 1 about spaces in the path, i will fix that then. This has indeed been a paim point and some of my OS Sampler steps really struggled with that until i solved that I needed single quotes around my path variables.         Regarding structure, my. Jmx file is in the parent path 'D:\SLAB Automation\Jmeter Scripts\' and hence I am editing files deeper in.      And i'll take a look at IDE option. Ive never used such before, so new territory there.

Comment: Hi @NigelDomaingue. It is a good practice to avoid spaces in file names and folder names. Running your script with an IDE can show if the issue is with JMeter or some external factor.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to work-around my problem rather than solve it in the manner I had originally considered. I had wondered if there were any Java methods which could poke the Windows OS level to either elevate file permissions or override them.  I know that Java is a VM and encourages portable code and thus such a solution would be against the spirit. Plus, it's way beyond my Java knowledge.

Anyway, I realised that the files I need to create also need to be specific to the test run in progress.  As my Jmeter script becomes more complex and may even have multiple Thread Groups running in parallel, I would not want a race condition on two TG's trying to use the same filename for different purposes.

Solution: Unique filenames per each context and test run. I store them in a folder specific for TempFiles, and even dynamically create monthly sub-folders within that to help with file admin on the host.  It's working, which is the main thing.